# Flexslider not working with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider, jquery-backstretch

I am using Flexislider to slide my images.

My HTML code is :

```
    <ul class='slides'>
    <li class="slide-two" >
        <div class="flex-div slide-stones2">
          <div class="slide-footsteps"> 
            <p>
                <span class="brown-bg">Take the steps to be who you want to be...</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="backstretch"> 
                     <img  src="img/massage-slider/slide-footsteps.jpg"/>
              </div>
       </div>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

I am trying to add selector like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    selector : ".slides>li>div>div>img",
                    animation : "slide",
                    controlsContainer : ".flex-container"
                });
            });
```

Comment: I don't see a `.flexslider` class anywhere in your HTML?

Comment: In the code you have posted, you forget to close ul tag (</ul> not <ul>). As Zenith pointed it, we cannot see .flexslider element in your code. BTW, do you want to use a flexslider for one image? I don't think so, but, who knows?! So, please consider to post relevant code not pseudo snippet this will help other users to focus on your issue.

Comment: Can you post the entire code that you have been working with

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is the issue

is with the selector

```
selector : ".slides>li>div>div>img",
```

supposed to be

```
selector : ".slides > ul > li > div > div.backstretch > img",
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `selector : ".slides>li>div>div"` is what you are looking for since there is no use of a slider for 1 image. It should work if you target the containing `<div>` IE. it does not need to be an `<li>`. I haven't seen a case where an `<img>` tag was the target selector.

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

Answer (score 0):

hey there are two div's in path `.slides > li > div`

now you are just writing `.slides > li > div > div > img`

which will try to find the image in first div so we have to define the div like this

`.slides > ul > li > div > .backstretch > img`

Answer (score 0):

I checked it on [zonemedia.sk](http://www.zonemedia.sk/)

HTML:

```
  <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
           <li><img src="img" alt="" /></li>
           <li><img src="img" alt="" /></li>
           <li><img src="img" alt="" /></li>
           <li><img src="img" alt="" /></li>
       </ul>
   </div><!-- .flexslider -->
```

JS:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        smoothHeight: true,
        useCss: true,
        touch: true,
        before: function(){
            $('body').each(function () {
              var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
            });
        },
        start: function(){
            $('body').each(function () {
              var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
            });
        },
        added: function(){
            $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
              var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh');
            });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you provided in your question does not contain the most relevant information : the slides container. Also, we have no idea which slider you are trying to use since it's not specfied in the question. I suggest that you provide all the relevant information when asking a question so people can understand what's going on around it.

However, I managed to find a working example on this [tutorial](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) that works like the one you partially provided and will summarize every steps.

First, make sure that every scripts have been included in the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Then, to get the slider to work, you obviously need an accessible container to work with. Let say it is `.slides_container`:

```
<div class="slides_container">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Finally, the slider needs to be activated like this (in the header):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.slides_container').flexslider();
});
```

As an advice, I suggest that you make sure that this basic example works *flawlessly* before adding any complexity to it. When it works as well, try with the easiest selector you can think of (ie: an element `#temp` so it is more likely to work as intended without any chance of debugging). The final case should be written only when you do know that every features are working.

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
  "image.jpg",
  "image.jpg",
  "image.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 750});
```